# Which coins do I have?

Tags: logical-deduction, money

I have **63** Rupees (or Dollars, or any kind of money).
I have no coin of value 1 (Rupee or Dollar) or less than 1.
(You can use coins like 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 500, 1000.)
Is it possible to have 63 without 1 rupee or dollar coin?  If yes, then how it is possible?

Comment: They are all fake and you have 7 bills of $9 each.

Comment: no coins are in 2,5,10,20,50,100 so 9 is not possible

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the PSE! On this site we have this strict rule, that if the puzzle isn't of your own creation, you need to explicitly state where it's from. You can also earn a badge by taking [the tour](/tour)!

Comment: You need to provide far more information - for example, what are the possible values for a bill, are coins usable (and if so, what values are available for them), is there a limit to the number of bills/coins I may use...

Comment: yes i forgot to do that.. i have edited question..

Comment: This seems to be an elementary maths textbook problem instead of a maths puzzle. Unfortunately, those have been deemed off-topic on this site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as writtten in the meta or more specific here: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2784/20

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You can get the right amount in six bills/coins like this: 50+5+2+2+2+2